# New Prestashop module is not showing in module list

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I'm creating a module for `Prestashop` 1.7 following [tutorial](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module), my actual code is like this:

`/themes/myTheme/modules/hwmodule/hwmodule.php`

```
class HwModule extends Module
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = 'hwmodule';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Lai';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
        $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if(!Configuration::get("MYMODULE_NAME"))
            $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
    }

}
```

As wrote in the documentation, this code is allow a basic installation, but when I can't find it in my module list (Admin > Module > Modules & Services).

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The module should be located at `/modules/hwmodule/hwmodule.php` instead. `themes/myTheme/modules/hwmodule/` you can place the theme tpl. For example, if you use a template in `/modules/hwmodule/views/template.tpl` you can modify for each theme the same template placing it in `themes/myTheme/modules/hwmodule/views/template.tpl`

Answer (score 0):

you should place your module in the right directory:
/prestashop/modules/modulename/modulename.php
else there is nothing wrong with your code or documentation of this topic at Prestashop 1.7 documentation.